# Pdf of Y knowing pdf of X

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Y=1-X^2, f_X(x)=\frac{3}{8} \cdot(x+1)^2 \cdot \mathbf 1_{(-1,1)}(x).$
I think the pdf of $Y$ should be the derivative of $F_Y(y)= F_X(-\sqrt{1-y} )-F_X(\sqrt{1-y})$, but it can't be negative. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The CDF of $X$ is
$$F_X(x) = P(X \le x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \le -1\\
\frac{1}{8} (x+1)^3 & -1 < x < 1
\\
1 & x \ge 1
\end{cases}$$

The CDF of $Y$ is
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \le y) = P(X \le -\sqrt{1-y}) + P(X > \sqrt{1-y})
\\&= F_X(-\sqrt{1-y}) + 1 - F_X(\sqrt{1-y}).
\end{align}
Note that you were missing a $+1$ in your CDF.

For $-1 < y < 1$, we have
$$F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{8} (1-\sqrt{1-y})^3 + 1 - \frac{1}{8}(1 + \sqrt{1-y})^3.$$

For $-1 < y < 1$, the derivative is
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) = \frac{3}{16} \frac{(1-\sqrt{1-y})^2 + (1 + \sqrt{1-y})^2}{\sqrt{1-y}}
= \frac{3}{8} \frac{2-y}{\sqrt{1-y}}.$$

Comment: Although this is quite obvious, you might want to point out that $F_Y(y)$  only has this form for $y < 1$ (or $y \leq 1$) and that $F_Y(y) = 1$ otherwise.

Comment: How do you know that for x>=1 you have $F_X(x)=1$?

Comment: @Student The density of $X$ is zero outside of $(-1, 1)$, so $P(X \le 1) = 1$.

Comment: I still don't understand, it's for $x>=1$

Comment: If $x \ge 1$, then $P(X \le x) \ge P(X \le 1) = 1$, so $P(X \le x) = 1$. @Student

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y \leq y) = \mathbb P(1 - X^2 \leq y) =  \mathbb P(X^2 \geq 1-y).$
Now, $\mathbb P(X^2 \geq 1-y) = \mathbb P(|X| \geq \sqrt{1 - y}) = \mathop{\mathbb P}\left(X \not \in \left(-\sqrt{1-y}, \sqrt{1-y}\right]\right)$ for $y < 1$ and  $\mathbb P(X^2 \geq 1-y) = 1$ otherwise (since the probability of $X$ taking a value at an interval boundary is zero due to the absolute continuity of the distribution of $X$).
Therefore, $F_Y(y) = \mathop{\mathbb P}\left(X \not \in \left(-\sqrt{1-y}, \sqrt{1-y}\right]\right) = 1- \left[\mathop{F_X}\left(\sqrt{1-y}\right) - \mathop{F_X}\left(-\sqrt{1-y}\right) \right]$ for $y < 1$  and $F_Y(y) = 1$ otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't P(-X^2<y-1) and then we change the sign when we multiply by -1?

Comment: @Student Can you follow the steps in my derivation now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!